# How exactly do you do transactions in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, transactions

I'm trying to figure out how to do transactions in SQLite, but I've hit a wall. Let's say I want to transfer $50 from one person's account to another. Take a look at the following code. It's heavily commented.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS accounts;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (
    name       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    balance    INTEGER         NULL -- Money is going to be stored in cents
);

INSERT INTO accounts (name, balance) VALUES
("John Doe",  10050), -- This means 100 dollars and 50 cents
                      -- because 100 dollars and 50 cents is
                      -- 100 * 100 cents + 50 cents = 10050 cents
("Bob Smith", 20000); -- 200 dollars



DROP VIEW IF EXISTS view_accounts;
CREATE VIEW view_accounts AS
    SELECT rowid,
           name,
           printf("$%.2f", balance / 100.0) AS balance
    FROM accounts;

SELECT * FROM view_accounts;
-- rowid       name        balance
-- ----------  ----------  ----------
-- 1           John Doe    $100.50
-- 2           Bob Smith   $200.00



BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Subtract $50 from John Doe's balance
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - 5000 WHERE rowid = 1;
-- And add $50 to Bob Smith's balance, but let's now intentionally
-- create something erroneous here. Let's say there's been a mistake
-- and we got the wrong rowid (maybe we received an id that does not
-- exist in our table from a host language such as PHP, but really it
-- could be anything from power-down to inadvertent reboot. I'm using
-- this particular example because it's easy to emulate an exceptional
-- situation). Instead of rowid 2, we mistakenly used a rowid of 3
-- which does not exist in our table.
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + 5000 WHERE rowid = 3;

-- Here's where I get stuck. What exactly should my next steps be?
-- What statements should I use here? Obviously I should roll all the
-- changes made so far back with the ROLLBACK command if something
-- exceptional happens, but I can't know that beforehand because the
-- value for rowid is received from external sources. On the other hand,
-- I can't use COMMIT either because what if in fact something
-- exceptional did happen? I somehow need to detect that something bad
-- has happened and conditionally either roll all the changes back or, if
-- everything is okay, commit them.
```

Comment: The error you described seems to be a problem in your business logic, so perhaps it should be up to the PHP script to correct it.  If your app layer can detect this error, you can use `ROLLBACK` to reverse the changes in the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in SQLite alone since SQLite does not have any flow control statements.

What you're looking for is similar to this pseudo-code:

```
IF rows-affected = 0 THEN ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Replace `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` with whatever type of error response you would like.

Since there is no `IF` statement or similar in SQLite syntax, you can't do it without the help of the code / programming language / runtime that uses SQLite.

In other words, the programming language that ends up calling into SQLite needs to look at the number of rows affected as reported by the SQLite engine, and deal with the zero.

Please note that the fact that you want to rollback a transaction is part of the response to the error, but this problem is not related to transactions as such. Basically your question is about flow control.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that I have to check from the host language whether there's been a problem and make a decision to either commit the changes or roll them back by sending COMMITs and ROLLBACKs to the SQLite environment?

Comment: Correct, there is no syntax in SQLite that can do this for you.

Comment: But how do I know there's a problem with my second SQL UPDATE statement? SQLite doesn't really show are errors when it's in transaction mode.

Comment: The code in the runtime that you use to call into SQLite should have support for checking the number of rows that was affected by the executed statement.

Comment: So, basically I need to use "SELECT changes() FROM accounts" after each UPDATE statement to see how many rows have been affected. If zero rows are affected, that means something wrong has happened and I need to roll everything back to what it was?